# EJB Injection error

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, weblogic, java-ee-6

I have an EAR file (JEE6) containing one ejb-jar (sample-ejb) file and one war file (sample-web).
Here is the structure:

```
sample-ear
         |----sample-ejb.jar
         |         |---TestEjb.java (@Singleton)
         |
         |----sample-web
                   |---StartupEjb.java (@Singleton,@Startup)
                   |---TestListener.java (@WebListener)
```

when I want to inject TestEjb to StartupEjb or TestListener:

```
@EJB
private TestEjb testEjb;
```

I get following error:

Glassfish:

```
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.sample.StartupEjb/testEjb,Remote 3.x interface =com.sample.TestEjb,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.sample.TestEjb,refType=Session into class com.sample.StartupEjb: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.sample.StartupEjb/testEjb' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
```

weblogic:

```
Caused By: weblogic.application.naming.ReferenceResolutionException: [J2EE:160200]Error resolving ejb-ref "com.sample.StartupEjb/testEjb" from module "sample-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" of application "com.sample_sample-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT". The ejb-ref does not have an ejb-link and the JNDI name of the target bean has not been specified. Attempts to automatically link the ejb-ref to its target bean failed because no EJBs in the application were found to implement the "com.sample.TestEjb" interface. Link or map this ejb-ref to its target EJB and ensure the interfaces declared in the ejb-ref are correct.
```

Both Glassfish and Weblogic can not find TestEjb!

By the way, when I create a remote interface for TestEjb and use that for injection it works well!
But I don't want to define remote interfaces and I want to use EJB with no interface. I don't think that I must define a remote interface for this simple usecase!

You can download the source code from here: https://dl.dropbox.com/sh/63hn3n9y3p5ypvi/SsG9iZIvx9/sample.zip?dl=1

It's a simple Maven project created using NetBeans.

Comment: I used @LocalBean and it worked.because I'm using JEE6 I don't need this annotation anymore but it does not work without it. weird ha!

Comment: Maybe it is wierd, but "no-view" doesn't between different deployment "entites" so you need some kind of view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You normaly MUST define a local interface, e. g.

```
@Singleton
@Local(PublicInterface.class)
public class MyBean implements PublicInterface {
  ...
}
```

If you explicitly avoid this interface you must mark your bean as @LocalBean:

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class MyBean {
  ...
}
```

PS: Code is untested but should help.

Comment: JEE6 sets a default implicit local interface. You don't really have to declare one.

Comment: Thanks BillR. The `@LocalBean` solution worked, but AFAIK for JEE6 we don't need `@LocalBean`. i'm using weblogic 12.1.1 and JEE6 project.

Comment: Yes, you're right, default of JEE6 works fine (as long as you do have exactly one interface).